# Upgrade to Gradle 2.6

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'd been looking in many websites and I haven't find a simple way to upgrade my gradle version to 2.6.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
        classpath "com.kageiit:robojava-plugin:1.1.5"

        classpath("net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.2.5") {
            exclude group: "xerces", module: "xercesImpl"
        }
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip
```

I'd like to just change the classpath and the distributionUrl and when I Sync project, it works.

Answer (score 5):

1. Change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip` (replace `2.6` with your desired version, as the day I speak it's the latest).
2. In your **root** `build.gradle`, **update Android gradle tools version** to `1.3.1`

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```

   3. **Sync** project with gradle files

Comment: I got the same Error: `No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getBootClasspath() is applicable for argument types: () values []`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go inside your project Folder.
2. Search for gradle-wrapper.properties
3. Edit the gradle-wrapper.properties in Notepad.
   You can see the following properties,change the distributionUrl to
   **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip**
   shown below.

   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip**